# Write base64 encoded string as Image with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ffmpeg, web-worker, html2canvas

I am using `FFmpeg` and `html2canvus` and trying to create an mp4 video with the screenshots taken from a slider.

here is my worker initialization

```
const worker = createWorker({
    //logger: ({ message }) => console.log(message),
    progress: (p) => console.log(p),
});
```

Then in click, I take the screenshots and putting into the video

```
const image2video = async () => {
    displayLoader();
    var zip = new JSZip();
    let selectedbanners = $(".selected_templates:checked");
    await worker.load();
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let Processed = 0;
        selectedbanners.each(async function () {
            var dataIndex = $(this).data('index');
            let ad = adTemplates[dataIndex];
            var innercounter = 0;
            $(`.template-container-${ad.name}`).each(async function () {
                var imgData;
                await html2canvas($(`.template-container-${ad.name}`)[innercounter], {allowTaint: true, width: ad.width, height: ad.height}).then(canvas => {
                    imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0).split('base64,')[1];
                    //await worker.write(`tmp.${ad.name}.${innercounter}.png`, imgData);

                });
                await worker.write(`tmp.${ad.name}.${innercounter}.png`, imgData);
                //await worker.write(`tmp.0.png`, `static/triangle/tmp.0.png`);   This is working
            });
        });
    });
};
```

I have setup a [codepen here](https://codepen.io/manoj-kumar-dhiman/pen/OJyRXeV). It works if I put the image path but doesn't work if I directly pass the base64 string.  [Here](https://github.com/ffmpegjs/ffmpeg.js/blob/master/docs/api.md#worker-write) I found that it also supports the base64 string as well as the URL.
This is how it looks in console
[image]
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed that just changed a line of code.

```
imgData = `data:image/png;base64,`+canvas.toDataURL('image/png', 1.0).split('base64,')[1];
```

In this, I just append a data URL and changed the image type from JPEG to png and it worked.